# Xamarin/XAML/C# - How do I set up my App.Current.Properties dictionary?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

**Problem:** I'm writing an app that calculates holiday leave days. On app start up, the user is prompted to enter their total number of leave days and this is stored in a static string called LeaveDays. I realised after reinstalling my app that the LeaveDays variable gets reset. Okay, so I need to save this data properly. I find that people often use the Application.Current.Properties option, so instead of assigning the LeaveDays variable to the value of the prompt entry, I assign it to the Application.Current.Properties["LeaveDays"] key.

Now my problem is that I don't have the key set anywhere and I'm getting a KeyNotFoundException. I think it should be set in the main App file but I don't want to instantiate it with any value. That value needs to come from the prompt. I'm sure I've just misread the documentation on this one but I'm not sure how the property dictionary should be set up and how it works with manual input.

Below is the code for my popup. Any help is much appreciated:

```
        async void SetLeaveDaysPopup()
    {
        VersionTracking.Track();

        var firstLaunch = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver;

        if (firstLaunch == true || ChangeLeaveDaysButton.IsEnabled == true)
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["LeaveDays"] = await DisplayPromptAsync("Set Leave Days", "Please set the amount of total leave days you have");
            EntitlementDaysText.Text = Application.Current.Properties["LeaveDays"] as string;
            calculateLeaveHours(EntitlementDaysText.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are setting the property twice, once using `DisplayPrompt` and once using the value of `EntitlementDaysText.Text`.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Apologies, have corrected now. The purpose is to set the text property of a field with this prompt property.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  At a glance it appears like it should work.

Comment: Upon app load, I am getting an KeyNotFound Exception: 'The given key 'LeaveDays' was not present in the dictionary.' Do I need to instantiate this somewhere else?

Comment: why is that very relevant information not included in your post?  First, you need to call `SaveProperties()` to make sure they are getting persisted to disk.  Second, you should check that the key exists before trying to access it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Have amended my post. Your answer is correct. The solution was to call the SavePropertiesAsync() method and check that the key exists in my property dictionary every time it's called. I will try and post my amended code above.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code with Jason's help:

```
async void SetLeaveDaysPopup()
    {
        VersionTracking.Track();

        var firstLaunch = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver;

        if (firstLaunch == true || ChangeLeaveDaysButton.IsEnabled == true)
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["LeaveDays"] = await DisplayPromptAsync("Set Leave Days", "Please set the amount of total leave days you have");
            await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("LeaveDays"))
            {
                EntitlementDaysText.Text = Application.Current.Properties["LeaveDays"] as string;
            }
            calculateLeaveHours(EntitlementDaysText.Text);
        }
    }
```